# non wodpress subdirectory refusing to serve https content

Tags: wordpress, apache, https, subdirectory, mixed-content

Runnin landing pages in a subdirectory below wordpress install;

public_html/comms
https pages in /comms display but scripts, css and images wont display.
If I remove the s and leave http then they will display perfectly within a https page.  How strange.
This only began a few days ago and only happens in chrome.
Works fine with edge and ie.
I need these landng pages to be https and no mixed content because google will penalise my quality score and adds will be more expensive.
I am lost for ideas.

Chrome problem only
In the subfolder only

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup forced SSL in the .htaccess file in the subdirectory root?

Add this to the file if it isn't there:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I thought of this, but the problem I am seeing is that http urls work fine and https fails.
I am assuming that the rewrite will send all requests to https
Surely that will make things worse.

If i did this in reverse, I suspect everything would work for now, but the thing is I need secure pages.

Have I grabbed the wrong end of the stick?